# Python newbie - Input strings, return a value to a web page

Tags: python, html, return-value

I've got a program I would like to use to input a password and one or multiple strings from a web page. The program takes the strings and outputs them to a time-datestamped text file, but only if the password matches the set MD5 hash.

The problems I'm having here are that

- I don't know how to get this code on the web. I have a server, but is it as easy as throwing pytext.py onto my server?
- I don't know how to write a form for the input to this script and how to get the HTML to work with this program. If possible, it would be nice to make it a multi-line input box... but it's not necessary.
- I want to return a value to a web page to let the user know if the password authenticated successfully or failed.

dtest

```
import sys
import time
import getopt
import hashlib

h = hashlib.new('md5')
var = sys.argv[1]
print "Password: ", var
h.update(var)
print h.hexdigest()
trial = h.hexdigest()
check = "86fe2288ac154c500983a8b89dbcf288"

if trial == check:
 print "Password success"

 time_stamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S', (time.localtime(time.time())))
 strFile = "txt_" + str(time_stamp) + ".txt"
 print "File created: txt_" + str(time_stamp) + ".txt"

 #print 'The command line arguments are:'
 #for i in sys.argv:
  #print i

 text_file = open(strFile, "w")
 text_file.write(str(time_stamp) + "\n")
 for i in range(2, len(sys.argv)):
  text_file.write(sys.argv[i] + "\n")
  #print 'Debug to file:', sys.argv[i]
 text_file.close()
else:
 print "Password failure"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to read up on [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/) (if you're using Apache) and the Python [CGI](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html) module.

Comment: Thanks. mod_python is what I needed to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/). It's an excellent web framework that can accomplish exactly what you are asking. It also has an authentication module that handles password hashing and logins for you.